# Netbeans: How do I upload changed files?

Tags: php, netbeans

I have a PHP project setup with Netbeans and a remote connection. I needed to work on something locally before uploading it to the live version. So I disabled `upload on save`, thinking that it's best to upload on run command, once I've done and tested all the changes that I'm going to do. When I clicked `run`, Netbeans asked me to select the files I wanted to upload. Of course, I thought to myself, Netbeans does not seem to keep a list of changed files in this project and this session particularily. So:

Is it possible to have Netbeans keep track for me of which files I've changed in this session and select and upload them easily?

Comment: I think no. It's better to consider other environments.

However, I can be wrong.

Comment: Why not using version control? Use a git repository and push. When done pull on the server.

Comment: @MarkusZeller Yes, seems to be the way to go. I just have no knowledge of Git. I need to find a Git for dummies guide.

Comment: This [guide](https://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/) is pretty nice.

Answer (score 0):

Try VisualCode with git/github plugin or sftp plugin.

```
https://code.visualstudio.com
```

It's amazing for php or c#/netcore (with couples php plugins).

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YH2kQ8kncrw

Install localhost server LAMP on windows

Or better Install Linux Debian or Ubuntu and set LAMP server on localhost.

Comment: This does not to rise to the level of an answer. Advising the user to install Visual Studio and/or LAMP and/or Linux is not a reasonable solution for a question that is specifically about using PHP on NetBeans. In general, radical answers suggesting _"Use tool {x} instead!"_ are unlikely to be helpful for solving the problem presented in the question.